# exit while loop after find first match

Tags: perl

I need to exit the loop after find first match and go to another search in the loop

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %iptv;
sub trim($) {
    my $string = shift;
    $string =~ s/\r\n//g;   
    $string =~ s/^\s+//;    
    $string =~ s/\s+$//;    
    return $string;

my @files=</tests/*>;
open IN, "/20131105.csv";
LINE: while (<IN>) {
        chomp;
         my @result = split(/;/,$_);
         my $result1 = trim($_);
         $result[1] = trim($result[1]);
         $iptv{$result[1]} = $result1;
    }
close IN;

foreach my $file (@files) {
        open FILE, "$file";
        while (<FILE>) {
                chomp;
                my ($mac, $date) = split(/;/,$_);               
                my @date1 = split(/\s/, $date);
                print "$iptv{$mac};$date1[0]\n" if defined $iptv{$mac};
                last LINE if (defined $iptv{$mac});
                }
close FILE;
}
```

I tried to use "last" function but it finds first match and ends program. where I have to put last?

Comment: Did you perchance get the error `Label not found for "last LINE"` and forget to mention that?

Comment: no, just didn't paste in my post

Comment: And? Does taking care of the rogue label work? Just mentioning, if an answer helped you, you can also accept it.

Comment: @user2075811 Not pasting in your code (and errors) is a very silly thing to do. After all, it's not like programming is an approximate science. The small details are what matters.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a look at the documentation:

```
$ perldoc -f last
last LABEL
last    The "last" command is like the "break" statement in C (as used
        in loops); it immediately exits the loop in question. If the
        LABEL is omitted, the command refers to the innermost enclosing
        loop. The "continue" block, if any, is not executed:

            LINE: while (<STDIN>) {
                last LINE if /^$/;  # exit when done with header
                #...
            }

        "last" cannot be used to exit a block that returns a value such
        as "eval {}", "sub {}" or "do {}", and should not be used to
        exit a grep() or map() operation.

        Note that a block by itself is semantically identical to a loop
        that executes once. Thus "last" can be used to effect an early
        exit out of such a block.

        See also "continue" for an illustration of how "last", "next",
        and "redo" work.
```

We can clearly read here about how to use `last`. If a label is omitted, it breaks out of the innermost loop. So only in the case where we do not want this do we use a label. You want this, so you do not want a label.

Some notes on your code:

Check the return value of `open`, and use three arguments with a lexical file handle.

```
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Cannot open $file: $!";
```

This also has the benefit that when the lexical variable `$fh` goes out of scope, the file handle is closed.

When you split on `\s` you split on a single whitespace. Most often, this is not what you want. If you for example have a date such as

```
$str = "Jan  1 2013"    # (note the two consecutive spaces)
```

...this will split into the list `"Jan", "", "1", "2013"` (note the empty field). This is only what you want if empty fields are relevant, such as with csv-like data. The default behaviour of `split` uses `' '` (a space character), which acts like `/\s+/`, except that it also strips leading whitespace.

Note that the two last statements inside this loop can be merged. Also, the use of the temp array `@date1` is not needed. So that your code looks like:

```
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Cannot open $file: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($mac, $date) = split /;/, $_;
    ($date) = split ' ', $date;
    if (defined $iptv{$mac}) {
        print "$iptv{$mac};$date\n" ;
        last;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach my $file (@files) {
    open FILE, "$file";
    LINE: while (<FILE>) {
            chomp;
            my ($mac, $date) = split(/;/,$_);               
            my @date1 = split(/\s/, $date);
            print "$iptv{$mac};$date1[0]\n" if defined $iptv{$mac};
            last LINE if (defined $iptv{$mac});
            }
close FILE;
}
```

Should make sure that you only exit the inner loop.
I suppose it would work just as well if you got rid of the LINE Label right behind the `last` alltogether but i would suggest allways using a label with `last` to be certain that it does not do something unexpected in case you add an additional inner loop and forget about the `last` within that you expect to leave a loop farther on the outside.